# Any way to alter script tag for some javascript and add custom attributes?

Tags: 7, javascript

In order to work with [Cloudflare's Rocket Loader service](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-), certain scripts need to have their script tags updated with the cf-async="false" attribute like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" cf-async="false">
```

Specifically, I need to add this attribute to the Drupal settings script tag, that gets added inline at the top of every page.

My first thought was to do this via hook_js_alter(), like:

```
function custom_helper_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $javascript['settings']['cf-async'] = 'false';
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be possible to add custom attribute tags via this function. So my question is, is there any way at all to do what I want without hacking core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, but it's not pretty. The markup produced by `drupal_get_js()` is pretty closed off; it uses `theme_html_tag()`, but what it provides for variables means identifying the Drupal.settings script is a pain.

This is about as good as you'll get. In custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_html_tag(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['element']['#tag'] == 'script' && strpos($vars['element']['#value'], 'jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings') === 0) {
    $vars['element']['#attributes']['cf-async'] = 'false';
  }
}
```

As you rightly mentioned through the comments you could also attack it at the theme override level instead of the module level. In template.php:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html_tag(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#tag'] == 'script' && strpos($variables['element']['#value'], 'jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings') === 0) {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['cf-async'] = 'false';
  }
}
```

If you have modules that mess with JavaScript (e.g. LabJS), the string match will be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks Clive for the helpful answer. I think you mean `MYTHEME_html_tag(&$vars)` in template.php, though, rather than MYMODULE_preprocess_html()?

Comment: I edited the original answer with the code that is working for me. Please feel free to re-edit, or update if that solution is not what you were intending.

Comment: It wasn't what I intended @Jordan, but your code is a perfectly valid alternative. I've changed the answer to include both

Comment: I changed the code again... I think this should be _preprocess_html_tag() in both cases (module and theme)... tested both and working as expected. hook_preprocess_html() gives different $vars that does not work with this code.

Comment: By using above approach this add attribute  cf-async after the src but to make it working we need to add before src as per documentation https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436--How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-  (point number 2 ) Please suggest how we can add it before src  ?