# Add custom attribute to an external JS script

Tags: 7, javascript

It's not really clear how to add custom attributes when adding an external JS script to the page.

Currently I have this code:

```
drupal_add_js('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js', array('type' => 'external'));
```

How can I add an `integrity` attribute to the rendered script tag?

The rendered script should look like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="></script>
```

I know [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152565/any-way-to-alter-script-tag-for-some-javascript-and-add-custom-attributes) post exists, but I'm not able to use that solution since the source is loaded externally and I will not be able to check on the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using `drupal_add_html` like this,

```
$data = array(
  '#tag' => 'script',
  '#value' => '',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'src' => 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js',
    'integrity' => 'sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($data, 'unique_key');
```

Comment: How to even use drupal_add_html ? is this a module which needs to be installed or what ???